# Recuperar variável de URL e repassar em AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Gostaria de saber se tem como após recuperar uma variável da URL passar para outra página e retornar o resultado em um `load`. Estou usando o seguinte *script* que recupera normalmente a variável, mas não passa para página seguinte. É apenas para entenderem melhor o que preciso.

Na URL `http://noticias.php?categoria=23`, pego a variável normalmente mas no `load` vem a informação que a página `resposta.php` não recebeu a variável.  Gostaria de passar para outra página antes de mostrar o resultado no `load`. Qual seria a forma correta?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#teste').html("<img src='js/load.gif'>");
    var variaveis=location.search.split("?");
    var quebra = variaveis[1].split("=");
    var categoria = + quebra[1];
    var URL='resposta.php';
    var dataString = 'categoria=' + categoria ;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: URL,
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $('#teste').load('resposta.php');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: usa o window.location pra vc receber os parametros

Comment: receber estou recebendo eu preciso reenviar antes de mostrar o resultado no load

Answer (score 1):

A forma correta de enviar para o parâmetro `data` é desta forma.

***Jquery***

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: URL,
    data: categoria,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
       $('#teste').load('resposta.php');
    }
});
```

ou em formato de um `Array`

***Jquery***

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: URL,
    data: { meuVar : categoria },
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
       $('#teste').load('resposta.php');
    }
});
```

E no PHP receberia desta forma

***PHP***

```
$categoria = $_POST["meuVar"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se isso tbm ajuda, mas da para passar o valor por get com o $.ajax assim:

```
var URL='resposta.php?'+dataString;

$.ajax(
{
url: URL,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
    $('#teste').load('resposta.php');
}
});
```

Se não me engano, pode tirar o type do $.ajax pq por padrão ele já trabalha com GET.